I am getting data from API but I am not getting data[1] values while showing data[0]. Is there a way to manually move data?
I am receiving api data from a modern application. I used API json response to do this. I will search for a word in the search box, but I cannot see the 1 values while I get the 0 values in the API. I would be glad if you can help me.
return ResponseModel.fromJson(data[0]); My data value is not increasing.
type here

class API {
  static const String baseUrl = "https://sozluk.gov.tr/gts_id?id=";

  static Future<ResponseModel> fetchMeaning(String word) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("$baseUrl$word"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      return ResponseModel.fromJson(data[0]);
    } else {
      throw Exception("failed to load meaning");
    }
  }
}

